# How implement .NET server and Python client?

Tags: c#, python, remoting

I've got a problem. I Have a tool(threads manager) that receives some data and do some computation. I need to write Python client to send data to that tool...I thing I should use .NET Remoting, but how to do that?
pls share some links where I can read or post some code...I can't google info about that...

P.S Python 2.7, NOT IronPython

Comment: Pick a protocol, write a server, write a client, done.

Comment: A little bit more details, please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net Remoting is designed for when you have **.net at both ends** so will be **very hard** to use from the Python end.  (Event the XML encoding of .net remoting is not easy to use from other platforms)

I am assuming that Python has support for soap, if so I would look at using WCF at the .net end running over the “basic profile”.  JSON is another option, there are lots of open source projects that add JSON support to .net, I assume that Python also has JSON surport.

Comment: I'm interested in "JSON" solution,could you please explain me in two words how does it work in my situation?

Comment: I run .NET app and send JSON to it from Python client? How to do that (how to add capability to .NET app to receive data in that way?)

Answer (score 1):

As for JSON, on .NET side you could try [JsonFx](http://jsonfx.net/). Then call it from python using any json-rpc client.

Answer (score 0):

I would use XML-RPC for communication. It is very simple to implement (a couple lines of code in Python, not sure about .NET but it shouldn't be difficult there either) and should be enough in your scenario.